# Div style not being applied when using getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I want to push an array of numbers into a div. I know the array will be long, so I want a maximum width so the numbers will continue to the next line. I have an example code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hy9Cb/)
and, as you can see, the maximum width doesn't seem to apply to the numbers -- they just keep running on one line. How do I get the width inside the class to apply to the numbers as well?

CSS:

```
.divstyle {
    background-color:orange;
    height:125px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divstyle">
<div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*99+1);
var num = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
    num.push(number);
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = num;
```

I'm betting I'm making a simple mistake, but I'm not familiar with CSS so there's that.

Comment: I don't think you can just write the entire object that is "num" out like that.  You have to tell it which element:  num[0].  Why are you pushing the number to an array to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your div's styling:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

If you want the numbers not to exceed the height of the div, add this to your div's styling too (maintains set height via scrollbar):

```
overflow: auto;
```

…Or add both of these (adjusts height to size of content):

```
height: auto;
min-height: 125px;
```

http://jsbin.com/vuvih/5/edit

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

> The `word-wrap` CSS property is used to specify whether or not the browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow (in other words, force wrapping) when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit in its containing box.

Comment: Or `height: auto;` and `min-height: 125px;`

Comment: Good call on the combined `auto` and `min` `height` (making sure to keep the `word-wrap` in that strategy, too)!

Answer (score 1):

It's because CSS "think" that is just one word, and do not break the line.

You should use

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = num.join(', ');
```

This way you will have the numbers separated by a comma and a space

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is your content is all considered one word. There is no whitespace between anything.

You need to specify

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

in order to force the breaking of words.

Here is an edit of your JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hy9Cb/2/

Here you can find all different value for word-break:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add  `word-wrap: break-word;` to your CSS, and to assure it doesn't overflow the box you can use `overflow: scroll;`

Check it out here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lmosb